# How to match an ip address in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex

For example, I am having a column storing data like this.

```
Apple
12.5.126.40
Smite
Abby
127.0.0.1
56.5.4.8
9876543210
Notes
```

How to select out only the rows with data in IP format?

I have tried with  `'^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$'`
but I have no idea why it also matches 9876543210

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're going to need to use `REGEXP` to match the IP address dotted quad pattern.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
  thecolumn REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$'
```

Technically, this will match values that are not valid IP addresses, like `999.999.999.999`, but that may not be important.  What *is* important, is fixing your data such that IP addresses are stored in their own column separate from whatever other data you have in here.  It is almost always a bad idea to mix data types in one column.

```
mysql> SELECT '9876543210' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| '9876543210' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                         0 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT '987.654.321.0' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| '987.654.321.0' REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                            1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Another method is to attempt to convert the IP address to a long integer via MySQL's [`INET_ATON()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton).  An invalid address will return `NULL`.

This method is likely to be more efficient than the regular expression.

You may embed it in a `WHERE` condition like: `WHERE INET_ATON(thecolumn) IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT INET_ATON('127.0.0.1');
+------------------------+
| INET_ATON('127.0.0.1') |
+------------------------+
|             2130706433 |
+------------------------+

SELECT INET_ATON('notes');
+--------------------+
| INET_ATON('notes') |
+--------------------+
|               NULL |
+--------------------+

SELECT INET_ATON('56.99.9999.44');
+----------------------------+
| INET_ATON('56.99.9999.44') |
+----------------------------+
|                       NULL |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I have tried with  '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$' but I have no idea why it also matches 9876543210

Comment: @AbbyChauYuHoi Double the backslashes. I always forget that when dealing with regexes in MySQL.

Answer (score 8):

[`IS_IPV4()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_is-ipv4) is a native mysql function that lets you check whether a value is a valid IP Version 4.

```
SELECT *
FROM ip_containing_table
WHERE IS_IPV4(ip_containing_column);
```

I don't have data, but I reckon that this must be the most solid and efficient way to do this.

There are also similar native functions that check for IP Version 6 etc.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the most efficient way, and it's not technically regex, but it should work:

```
SELECT col1 FROM t1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%.%.%.%';
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also use the useful function inet_aton()

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE inet_aton(thecolumn) is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Lengthy but works fine:

```
mysql> SELECT '1.0.0.127' regexp '^([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$';
```