# find IP addresses in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table in mysql.
the table has one column which is UserName.

Now, there are regular names in it and some IP addresses in it.
How can I show in a query only the IP addresses?

Keep in mind that there are names like this

> a.b.c.d

So, if I write this

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE UserName LIKE '%.%.%.%'
```

it will not do the job for me.
I need only the IP address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699056/how-to-match-an-ip-address-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE UserName REGEXP '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$';
```

Note: [Select * is Evil](http://www.parseerror.com/blog/select-*-is-evil)

**Edit:**

Depending on MySQL version this may be a better alternative:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE UserName REGEXP '^[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}$';
```

Comment: I receive this error. Error Code: 1139. Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp

Comment: Interestingly it runs fine on MariaDB. The commenter on your original thread linked to another similar answer with a different regex, I've updated the original answer with that too for your reference :)

Comment: One more thing. Why does it miss some values? such as this value, 12.226.118.75

Comment: @user3882752 `SELECT '12.226.118.75' REGEXP '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$';` = 1 for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
 From table1
WHERE UserName REGEXP '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){1,3}[0-9]{1,3}$'
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, it is still a good idea to add some explanation and, possibly, some links to the relevant documentation. Answers with good explanations and references are usually more useful both to the current OP and to the future visitors. Full detailed answers are also more likely to attract positive votes.